# Remove rows from a result set that may include the same email address

Tags: mysql, x-cart

I have the following MySQL query.

```
SELECT
    login,
    firstname,
    lastname,
    email
FROM
    xcart_customers
WHERE
    login LIKE 'anonymous%'
AND email NOT IN (
    SELECT
        email
    FROM
        xcart_customers AS cx
    WHERE
        cx.login NOT LIKE 'anonymous%'
)
GROUP BY
    email;
```

Basically there are two sets of customers, customers that have logins, and anonymous customers who all start with a login of 'anonymous%'.

I am trying to remove non-anonymous users from the list, that have the same email address as the anonymous users.

I thought the above query would have worked, but I still get some emails addresses that match non-anonymous users.

```
login           |  firstname     |   lastname     |   email
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
anonymous-10    |  Eric          |   Byorn        |   byorn@mail.com
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
some_user_name  |  Eric          |   Byorn        |   byorn@mail.com
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

So I am trying to solve, all anonymous users, who only appear in the anonymous results.

Comment: Can you share some data?

Comment: Ok, added example data @shmosel

Comment: Your query returns 0 rows with your sample data. Can you give an example of an unexpected result?

Answer (score 1):

The most efficient, and IMHO elegant, solution is to use an outer join:

```
SELECT
  a.login,
  a.firstname,
  a.lastname,
  a.email
FROM xcart_customers a
LEFT JOIN xcart_customers b ON b.email = a.email
  AND b.login NOT LIKE 'anonymous%'
WHERE a.login LIKE 'anonymous%'
AND b.email IS NULL
```

There's two key tricks in play here:

1. Because missed LEFT JOINs return all NULLs in the left joined table, the WHERE clause *excludes* rows that *have* a match
2. *All* conditions (even non-key) on the joined table must be in the join condition, ie *not* in the WHERE clause, otherwise to efficively turn the outer join into an inner one

---

Note that your use of `GROUP BY` is both flawed and unnecessary.

Comment: Except that I still get duplicate email addresses in the results, if there are multiple anonymous rows from the same checkout customer.

Comment: You didn't say anything about duplicates. Does `SELECT DISTINCT ...` work? If not, ask a new question (because this question has been answered)